# vba excel: how to copy characters from a cell to another

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new in VBA world and I'm learning by your suggestions.

I've looked for several solutions, tried them but they were't ideal for my problem.

Here are the links

[Find a string within a cell using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10904012/find-a-string-within-a-cell-using-vba)

[How to Count the Number of a Specific Character in a Cell with Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21371817/how-to-count-the-number-of-a-specific-character-in-a-cell-with-excel-vba)

[Which command in VBA can count the number of characters in a string variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1725089/which-command-in-vba-can-count-the-number-of-characters-in-a-string-variable)

What I need is the possibility to check the characters in`Input` and match with `Match list key`. After matched the string, copy the characters I in output.

[image: Here and example in sheet]

As you can see, first rows are simple to match but in `A8` cell (for example)  there is a string with fourteen characters.
In this case I need that, when there is a string that begin with CMXXAB, the match is with WT (ALWAYS!). 
The same thing happen when we have A12: it begins with ETRxxx and, after match will begin in output like JAZZ.

Comment: If you show us your code, you will get much better help!

Comment: well I haven't got. I’m trying to generate one but my experience now is limited 

Comment: Any other **special rules** other than the one's for `JAZZ` and `WT`?  Also, your screenshot of data is virtually useless for doing proper troubleshooting. It cannot be copy/pasted into a worksheet. Having to manually enter it is discouraging to those who might assist you. To make the data useful edit your question to post it as text, perhaps using this [Markdown Tables Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables), or possibly upload a workbook (with sensitive information removed) to some public website and post a link in your original question.

Comment: The special rules are only for jazz and wt

Comment: And what exactly do you mean by `CMXXAB`?

Comment: As you can see in shoot, there are several of string that begin in CM. All three begin with CM00PR but they could be CM01VC or CM06VE. Hope I’ve been clear

Comment: So do you mean any string that starts with `CM`?  or do you mean any string that starts with `CM0`?  Or something else?

Comment: Any strings that starts with CM

Comment: OK, add a comment addressed to me after you've posted usable data, and I'll check back.

Comment: Also, I note that row 9 does not start with `CM` yet you show `WT`.  What is the logic behind that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will help you:

```
Option Explicit

Sub test()

    Dim LastrowA As Long, i As Long, AppearA As Long, AppearB As Long
    Dim strA As String, strB As String


    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

        LastrowA = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        For i = 1 To LastrowA

            strA = .Range("A" & i).Value
            strB = .Range("C" & i).Value

            'Check if strA appears in strB
            AppearA = InStr(1, strB, strA)
            If AppearA > 0 Then
                .Range("B" & i).Value = strA
                Exit For
            End If

            'Check if strB appears in strA
            AppearB = InStr(1, strA, strB)
            If AppearB > 0 Then
                .Range("B" & i).Value = strB
                Exit For
            End If

        Next i

    End With

End Sub
```

> Thank you so much for help. 
>   after few days i've found solution for problem in my question.
>   infact, this is my solution and I hope to be good for helping anyone need something like this.

```
Sub AssociazioneRotabiliPerPivot()

Dim LastrowA, LastrowC As Long, i, j As Long, AppearA As Long, AppearB As Long
Dim strA As String, strB As String

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet1")

    LastrowA = .Cells(.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastrowC = .Cells(.Rows.count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    For j = 1 To LastrowC   

        For i = 1 To LastrowA   

            strA = .Range("A" & i).Value
            strB = .Range("C" & j).Value

            AppearC = InStr(1, strA, strB)
            If AppearB > 0 Then
                .Range("B" & i).Value = strB
            End If

            If (InStr(1, strA, "CM") Or InStr(1, strA, "C4551R")) > 0 Then

                .Range("B" & i).Value = "WT"   

            ElseIf InStr(1, strA, "ETR425") > 0 Then   

                .Range("B" & i).Value = "JAZZ"  

            End If

        Next i

    Next j

End With
```

End Sub